# Rails: Store large blob in mysql so that delayed_job can read it later

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am working on an export/import functionality to transfer data from one application to other.

I have a delayed job to carry out the importing task. I need to pass a json file to the delayed job for which I am trying to write the file to the database. The  max possible size of json file is 20 megabytes.

Since the application is deployed on a multiple server setup, I cannot write file to the disk and read it from the disk in the delayed job.

Question:
I am not able to add a binary column with 25 megabyte size even though I specify the limit in the migration as shown below

```
class CreateImports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :imports, :force => true do |t|
      t.binary     :upload_data , :limit => 50.megabyte
      t.timestamps
    end
   end

  def down
    drop_table :imports
  end
end
```

It is creating a schema like this

```
create_table "imports", :force => true do |t|
    t.binary   "upload_data",     :limit => 2147483647
    t.datetime "created_at",                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            :null => false
end
```

which is not allowing me to store more than a 2 MB blob. 
How do I approach this problem?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you DO NOT DO THIS, and instead figure out how to have a shared folder between your multiple servers in which this can live as a file.  If you store 20 MB data blobs you will massively bloat out your database which will have all sorts of negative consequences, eg backing up, data transfer times, memory etc.